# Jenkins - define json using environment variable

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to add an environment variable containing a json which needs to give out the deployed branch name like below:

```
stage('Build files') {
    agent { label "${AGENT_NAME}"}
    environment {
       DEPLOYED_BRANCH = '{\"branch\":\"${env.BRANCH_NAME}\"}'
    }
    steps { //Do something}

    ansiColor('xterm') {
    sh """
    echo \"${DEPLOYED_BRANCH}\" > deployed_branch.json
    """
    }
}
```

While deploying, I am getting :

```
 "{"branch":"${env.BRANCH_NAME}"}": bad substitution
```

I've tried a few different options with the single/double quotes but with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this, but it will be a JSON string in the deployed_branch.json file (JSON file with a string content)

```
stage('create a JSON ') {
   environment {
       SOME_ENV_VARS = '{\"branch\":\"$WORKSPACE\"}'
   }
   steps { 
      sh """
          echo $SOME_ENV_VARS > deployed_branch.json
      """
   }
}
```

It can be done better way like this:

**scripted pipeline**

```
node {
  stage('any') {
     def myJSON = readJSON text: '{}'
     myJSON.branch = "${env.WORKSPACE}" as String
     writeJSON file: "${WORKSPACE}/x.json", json: myJSON
  }
}
```

**declarative pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('create a JSON ') {
            steps { 
                script {
                    def myJSON = readJSON text: '{}'
                    myJSON.branch = "${env.WORKSPACE}" as String
                    writeJSON file: "${WORKSPACE}/x.json", json: myJSON
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note - it need [Jenkins Utility Pluigns](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/)